# Таблица на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование, адаптивная-верстка, таблицы, оптимизация-сайтов

Условия: есть сайт, на котором выложен прайс(реализован с помощью таблицы).

Проблема: при просмотре на компьютере, ноуте, планшете все ОК. При просмотре на телефоне нормально только если посетитель перевернул телефон в горизонтальное положение. В вертикальном все съезжает. Для клиента ничего не понятно к чему какая цена.

Вопрос: Контора, которая обслуживает сайт утверждает, что сделать ничего нельзя. Но мне как то слабо верится. Неужели нет кода для изменяемого размера ячеек в соответствии с размером экрана? Сама не раз видела сайты, где с компа на всю страницу, а с телефона столбцы уменьшаются. Да, текст иногда в таких случаях выглядит неважно, но хоть понятно какая цена к какому наименованию
Кода не прошу, прошу сказать неужели это действительно невозможно?

Comment: Вы можете привести пример вашей таблицы/прайса? Вертикальная ориентация телефона предоставляет не так много места для "маневра" с таблицами...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Требуется больше информации, лучше скрины, чтобы понять что именно вы хотите узнать, просто по вашему описанию, можно сделать, но дать уверенно ответ не можем(лично Я).

Comment: Обычно на моб. устройствах или  перестраивают таблицу, но это очень зависит от количества колонок и количества информации в них, так как при уменьшении до определенного размера, информация будет просто нечитаема, или добавляется скролл на таблицу, когда таблица +/- таких же размеров как на десктопе, но ее можно потянуть пальцем горизонтально (проскролить), чтобы увидеть информацию которая не поместилась в экран.